# How to install the OpenJDK 8 (Ubuntu 19.04)?

Tags: jdk, openjdk, 19.04

Only openjdk-11-jdk and newer seem to be available. Is there any way to install the OpenJDK 8? Preferably without adding a PPA.

Comment: You may download `jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz` (185.98 MB) directly from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html and install it at `/opt/jvm` or any where you wish. Please note that this **NOT** `open jdk 8`.

Comment: @Marmayogi That wouldn't enable auto-updates. Preferably a solution would include an auto-update feature.

Comment: That is known thing @Andrew. It is up to questioner's choice. I too installed Oracle JDK 11 on /opt/jvm. Now JDK-12 is out and I just downloaded little while ago and going to install. One advantage is that I can switch  between JDK-11 and JDK-12 whenever need arises.

Comment: I made it very clear @FliegendeWurst that the download URL is for Oracle JDK-8 and **NOT** for `open jdk 8`.

Comment: I was hoping to find a PPA from the fine people over at https://adoptopenjdk.net - but haven't been able to find one yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of now, 30 April 2019 02:00 UTC, Open JDK 8 and its associated packages have been added back to the normal Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo repositories.

So you can now do the usual

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

without adding any PPAs or downloading .deb packages.

---

As an aside, I believe the package was removed from 19.04 (while originally being there) because it was (erroneously?) removed from Debian testing ([related bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=915620)) and then cleaned up downstream. It has been re-added today by its maintainer Matthias Klose aka doko.

Comment: I just tried this on 11 May 2019 11:21 BST but it prints `E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk` - it seems to not be available again?

Comment: I can see from their website that it's in disco-updates in universe (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco-updates/openjdk-8-jdk). Do you have that enabled in your system? Open "Software & Updates" and on the "Ubuntu Software" tab, enable "...(universe)" and on the "Updates" tab enable "Recommended updates (disco-updates)"

Comment: Thanks, it was the "Recommended updates (disco-updates)" in the "Updates" tab that wasn't enabled - I'm guessing this was because I chose to do a minimal installation rather than full one.

Answer (score 12):

While PPA is the preferred method to install JDK 8 in order to get timely updates and fixes, but if you still want to install **without PPA**, you can download and install JDK 8 from Ubuntu's pool of Universe packages.

- Download JDK and JRE:

  ```
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
  wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install using dpkg:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb \
  openjdk-8-jre_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb \
  openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb \
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
  ```
- Install dependencies:

  ```
  sudo apt install -f
  ```

---

If you want to install using PPA, add openjdk-r ppa and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-8-jre
```

Answer (score 5):

Kulfy's answer is working for me. However, I had to make some changes in order to make it work on Ubuntu 19.04.

1. Download JRE and JDK:

   ```
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
   wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Try to install using `dpkg` (`\` didn't work for me, just use spaces):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jre_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. If you have missing dependencies, and error will be shown. Install the dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install -f
   ```
4. After installing the dependencies, try to install again (Go to step 2).

Answer (score 1):

1. Press on left/bottom corner on  'show applications' or 'windows button'
2. Open Software & Updates
3. Make sure you have these 2 checked
   [image: Update Software -> universe]

[image: Updates -> disco-update]
4. Close(update)
5. Restart 
Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

On Launchpad [OpenJDK builds (all archs)](https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has ALL the versions of java JRE/JDK (OpenJDK