# How to install Java 8 on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: lubuntu, java, jdk, jre, 19.04

I upgraded my system to the latest Ubuntu. However, it seems that it's shipped with java 11. I removed it because I need  Java 8. However, it seems that Java 8 won't install on my system and I was googling and I stumbled by this: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java
How can I install Jre and jdk 8 on my system?

Comment: I just want to run some JavaFX project in netbeans

Comment: I get this message when I use JDK 11: The JDK you are using does not support JavaFX..

Comment: tried that now. Didn't work. Still have the same error

Comment: @Kulfy he is saying that "PPA has been discontinued as of April 16, 2019 (reference). So it's better to delete it." so it's not beneficial

Comment: @Kulfy I was able to install Java 8 thanks a lot. However, my problem: the JDK you are using does not support JavaFX hasn't got solved yet

Comment: I created a post on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767178/error-the-jdk-you-are-using-does-not-support-javafx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download deb packages from old repositories, my answer assumes you have amd64.

Download debs

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
```

Install them

```
sudo dpkg -i openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jre_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jdk_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1_amd64.deb
```

Install missing dependency packages

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: I was trying to install Minecraft on 19.04 and couldn't get Java 8 installed. This answer worked perfectly.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1139285/165511  30 April 2019 so in terminal  `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` this worked for me