# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: error-handling

I am trying to run this command `java -Dprism.forceGPU=true -jar QV.jar`. I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 10 more
```

I have tried to search for similar questions but the two I found are not closely related to mine.

If I right click on the file, I have the option to run it using JRE but nothing happens I do that.

Comment: I think [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136420/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javafx-application-application) ought to answer your question

Comment: You are right ! It is working now.